# How do I go back to the beginning of the function in asynchronous structure?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, callback

I don't know if the problem is asynchronous but my code didn't work here How do I get it to recheck every second on the else side if the if function in dat().then is false? Currently my dat() function in settimeout is not working. I didn't expect it to work anyway

```
var dat = async () => {
        await document.querySelector("body").click();
}

dat().then(() => {
    if(document.querySelector("body").className.indexOf("position") == -1){
       console.log("right");
    }
    else setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);

})
dat();
```

Comment: `else return promisifiedSetTimeout(dat, 1000)`. however, `document.querySelector("body").click()` doesn't return a promise, so, making this an async function and looping it this way is way more complex than necessary to simply call a function every n seconds until a condition is true. Is this actually what you're trying to do? or is this simplified for something more useful

Comment: I uploaded the process by simplifying it much more complicated. the code you gave

Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: promisifiedSetTimeout is not defined

It returns an error like

Comment: Right, that's a made up function that you'd need to create, sorry

Comment: What is `setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);` supposed to achieve? Notice that arrow functions have no own `arguments`, and `callee` is deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my attempt to write your code with the looping the stated desired loop.

```js
var dat = async () => {
    await document.querySelector("body").click();
}

const unclicked = () => (
    document.querySelector("body").className.indexOf("position") == -1);

do {
    await dat();
    if (unclicked())
        console.log("right");
    else
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
} while (true)
```

However, I admit I agree with Kevin B's comment in that `setTimeout` and `document.querySelector(...).click() don't return Promises.

If you care to comment, I will gladly update the answer to reflect the question.